How to recover lost files from Windows 10?
I had manually backed up a folder with photos and videos into the C: SSD drive -> User -> Administrator -> Documents  -> SAMSUNG BACKUP -> DCIM folder.
3 weeks ago, I took out a subfolder from inside this DCIM folder and left it outside of the main folders in DCIM.
2 weeks ago, when I went to check it, that subfolder containing photos and videos is missing. It is like it vanished off of the face of the Earth. Can you tell me:

How I can recover it?
How can I get a log of what happened to this subfolder if I don't have any backups or restore points or auditing setup on my Windows?

These were lasting memories which I will never be able to get back. I want to recover these files.

Regular computers don't really log changes to files on the drive. Do you know the drive is OK? There are a couple data recovery questions with decent answers already on this site. Have you reviewed these yet and tried anything? Please also note that actually using the computer these pictures were lost on WILL decrease the chances those pictures can be recovered, and for the best chance of getting most of your data back, you'll want to use a second computer to perform the recovery, connecting that SSD using a USB drive cradle of some sort.
